# Full Screen broken - Stock Tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm trying to use full screen from stock tools but it's not working. I've searched all related questions and documentation but couldn't find any working example with `react`. Maybe the problem is with it's wrapper or the way I'm initializing it and/or calling it.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/full-screen-issue-stock-tools-ehmro?file=/src/CustomGUIChart.js) is a demo attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it 3 weeks ago: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13175

PR: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/pull/13176

It ill be a part of a next release 8.0.5 or 8.1.0.

If you need it now, you can find a fix in the commit above. If you don't know how to do it, let me know and I will prepare a demo with a workaround for you.

Edit: actually, a simple workaround is in the ticket above.